# Overlay Video On UiImageView Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, avplayer

Can anyone help me, how can I overlay video on an image view, for example adding a background image to video, is it possible in swift xcode? [image: i want a picture in background and video is in the middle like this]

Comment: Is the video transparent?

Comment: No , it is a video fetched from library

Comment: Avplayer is not set to fill the image view so aides of the image will be visible

Comment: If the video isn't transparent, then the image will never be displayed. Why do you then need an image view?

Comment: @SylvanDAsh check the screenshot I attached

Comment: So more like adding a `UIVisualEffectView` to the video?

Comment: Okay I don’t know about it , can you explain a little how can I achieve the above task and can I use ScrollView to zoom in and zoom out video to change its position and scale and save it ??? Thanks in advance